# use return value assignment within while statement

Tags: c#, while-loop, assign

If I do this

```
while((e = data.IndexOf('}', at)) >= 0
      &&
      (s = data.LastIndexOf('{', at, e-1)) >= 0)
```

in C#, will the value of e in the second expression already have the value assigned within the while statement?

Answer (score 3):

You can always try it out.

Short answer: Yes

Long answer: I rather create easier to read code because that kind of programming does not optimize anything. It might be opinion-based but i strongly believe it's a best practice and provides better code maintenance.

```
while(e = data.IndexOf('}', at)) >= 0)
{
  s = data.LastIndexOf('{', at, e-1))
  if(s < 0)
    break;
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Surely you mean less/easier code maintenance with your example, not higher:)

Answer (score 0):

According to the spec, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa691322, evaluation is left to right:

> For example, in F(i) + G(i++) * H(i), method F is called using the old
>   value of i, then method G is called with the old value of i, and,
>   finally, method H is called with the new value of i.

So yes, e will be assigned to the result of `data.IndexOf('}', at)`, then `data.LastIndexOf('{', at, e-1)` will use that 'new' e.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you've used `&&` operator, which evaluates left side first to check if evaluation of the right side is necessary.

> The conditional-AND operator (`&&`) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, but **only evaluates its second operand if necessary**.
>
> *from [&& Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx)*